# How to change PR merge commit message?

Tags: azure-devops

When pull requests are created, their commit message is always like "Merged PR### from {branch name} into {target branch name}"

I keep amending commit messages and this is a bit tiring. I rely on the commit messages to keep track, so the automatic messages present a problem.

Comment: If you don't squash commits, you'll get the complete history of the developer's changes. They can clean up the commit history prior to opening their PR. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops

Comment: You can also navigate to the PR to see the details long after it's been completed and the originating branch has been deleted. The PR is a hyperlink when looking at commit history from the Azure DevOps repository view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature of Azure DevOps, the purpose is making it clearly to describe what happened for each commit.

For the commit message with a merged commit by pull request, the default commit message is defined by the git server side (such as Azure DevOps, github etc) where your git repo hosted.

And it's a good habit to **add the pull request information in commit message** since the commit is merged by PR.

As you found, the default merge commit message in VSTS pull request like `Merged PR <pull request ID>: branch1 to branch2`.

Additional, such as GitHub, the default merge for pull request like `Merge pull request #<pull request ID> from account/branch`.

If you want to **use your own commit message for merging Azure DevOps pull request**, just **custom the commit message as you need in the text box** before clicking Complete merge button (such as change the default message `Merged PR 118: master to b1` in text box in below example).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I could not find an editable commit message during the PR setup. When I noticed "Complete merge" button on your screenshot, I reviewed the PR setup more carefully and found this dialogue under "Set auto-complete" option. I'll add this to my project's documentation.

Comment: Trying to get developers to remember to do this everytime is pretty futile. It would be nice to be able to customise the convention used.

Comment: What I consider even more annoying is the fact that the current Azure DevOps merge commit message template violates the [best practice](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/) for Git subject message and Git native behaviour ADO: Merged PR xx ... vs. Git: Merge branch ...

Comment: Revisiting this in 2021: Is there a way to set default commit merge messages?

Comment: A default commit message template would be wonderful. The "Merged " prefix is pure clutter.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set a default commit merge message (or at least set it to follow the Git practices). Did someone come up with a solution?

Comment: I think the best way forward would be to upvote the feature suggestions on the Azure dev community board. If you search for it, someone has already posted it there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?sort=votes&type=idea&openOnly=true

Comment: [Direct link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Customizable-templates-for-the-default-m/1486969) to the feature request.

Comment: @Frédéric That is a duplicate of this feature request, which also has more votes. (Seems like Microsoft has ignored this for years)
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/change-default-title-for-pull-request-commits-to-n-1/365716

Comment: "And it's a good habit to add the pull request information in commit message since the commit is merged by PR."

Yes, but _not in the commit subject_. I think it would be better to put in the footer, something like

pr: #1234