# Azure DevOps - Change the pull request title length so that the message is no longer cut off

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps seems to have a default limit for the commit title, after which it will stop and add ellipsis. I would like to change this behavior so that the full first line of the commit message is included in pull request title. At the very least I am hoping there is a way to specify a large character limit if there is no option to turn it off.

I have done some googling and poked around in the settings on the project and have not discovered anything that seems like it would do what I want. I have full access to the project so permissions should not be an issue for me.

For those who may be wondering: The title of the ticket is commonly used in the commit title. These titles may be long in some instances and as a result of this behavior frequently get cut off. Makes it difficult to figure out what the changes could be related to at glance when scrolling though the commit history.

## **Edit:**

[Created a feature request on DevOps community.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1027317/allow-a-configurable-length-to-the-automatic-pull-1.html)

Comment: Fully agree with Simon Ness. Since it is called a title, it should be concise, not all inclusive. On the other side, you hover your mouse over the ellipsis, you will see all the content.

Comment: For  us the Title is the title of the ticket. Maybe a character limit makes sense when developing something open source as it prevents long names from being unintentionally committed but for us this does not make sense. The title of the ticket gives enough information at a glance to describe the changes for the ticket. When the title is cut off, I have to go look up in ticket in Jira to figure out at a glance what was changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change PR merge commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636169/how-to-change-pr-merge-commit-message)

Comment: No it does not. That question is asking how to change the default commit message after the pull request has been created. I am wondering how to change the pull request message default length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to disable this functionality, it seems like Github, Azure Devops does this to keep PR titles succinct for UI purposes and perhaps a nudge to make things easier for the reviewer.  It's still possible to make the PR title longer though by manually editing it.  You could suggest a new feature on [Azure DevOps' developer community site](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5890) to allow disabling this default functionality.

Whilst a the change set describes *what* has changed a good commit message will describe *why* it changed.  Understandably you don't want to lose the *why* context, some alternatives to achieving this are:

- Text that appears in the PR description is also included in the PR's commit message, albeit on separate lines.  This is a chance to add more context.  You could even nudge developers to do this with a [pull request template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops).
- Some PRs are a series of commits that tell a story, each commit in isolation gives good *why* context for the related change.  In this case it might make sense to opt not to do a [squash commit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/pull-requests-with-rebase/) to preserve the original commit messages.  You can even restrict the allowed merge types in branch policies.
- You mention "title of the ticket", if you are using Azure DevOps Boards as your ticketing system, there are several ways for a PR to [link back to that ticket](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/) should the ticket include lots more context that's inappropriate to duplicate in the PR description.  Perhaps the simplest way is to include a hash and the story number (e.g. #123) in the commit message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: We use Jira so linking the commit is not an option at this time. This is why we put the ticket number and the title of the ticket in the title of the commit. When scrolling through the commit history we can easily see what ticket was completed and what feature it was related to. When the title is cut off I need to look up the title in Jira, which defeats the purpose of scrolling through the history to find possible commits of interest.